# "Could not parse uri [redirect_uri]" when trying to authenticate

Tags: support, authentication, url-syntax

I was just reading into this API and wanted to test it out before I would use it in a project.

I have added an application on this site and got all of the keys.

When I try to authenticate a user with the following URL (according to [this manual](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=[id]&scope=private_info&redirect_uri=[git username].github.io/[git repository name]/
```

When I go to that URL in a browser I get the following error:

> Could not parse uri [`[git_username].github.io/[git repository name]/`]

I have made sure that the redirect_uri is in accordance to my specified `OAuth Domain` as you could find in your own app here [https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/[id]](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/%5Bid%5D).

I have also tried URL encoding the URI but that didn't make any difference.

I hope you could help me with this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not explicitly mentioned in the documentation (perhaps because it uses the term URI, and says it must be 'under' a domain), but for the redirect URI I always use a 'full' address, including the scheme. E.g. `https://example.github.io/example-repository/`; could you give that a try? URL encoding the URI isn't necessary; [forward slashes are allowed in the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375597/4751173).